# Nokogiri does not load parse whole xml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a XML document:

```
<event>
    <type>SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER</type>
    <marketplace>
        <baseUrl>https://www.acme-marketplace.com</baseUrl>
        <partner>ACME</partner></marketplace>
    </marketplace>
    <creator>
        <email>admin@fakeco</email>
        <firstName>Alice</firstName>
        <lastName>Hacker</lastName>
        <openId>https://www.acme-marketplace.com/openid/id/a11a7918-bb43-4429-a256-f6d729c71033</openId>
        <uuid>a11a7918-bb43-4429-a256-f6d729c71033</uuid>
    </creator>
    <payload>
        <company>
            <uuid>d15bb36e-5fb5-11e0-8c3c-00262d2cda03</uuid>
            <email>admin@fakeco</email>
            <name>Fake Co.</name>
            <phoneNumber>1-415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <website>fakeco</website>
        </company>
        <order>
            <editionCode>BASIC</editionCode>
            <item>
                <quantity>10</quantity>
                <unit>USER</unit>
            </item>
        </order>
    </payload>
</event>
```

and I got strange result when I load it with nokogiri:

```
1.9.3p194 :056 > doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml")).to_s
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<event>\n    <type>SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER</type>\n    <marketplace>\n        <baseUrl>https://www.acme-marketplace.com</baseUrl>\n        <partner>ACME</partner></marketplace>\n    </event>\n"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two closing `</marketplace>` tags, which is invalid XML:

```
    <partner>ACME</partner></marketplace>
</marketplace>
```

Remove one of them and Nokogiri should read the file fine.

Comment: Oh man I've just realized it too.. I should have open it in some syntax-highlighter :-). Thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome! It's pretty easy to find, just look where Nokogiri stopped, and you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse your XML into a Nokgiri::XML document:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<event>
    <type>SUBSCRIPTION_ORDER</type>
    <marketplace>
        <baseUrl>https://www.acme-marketplace.com</baseUrl>
        <partner>ACME</partner></marketplace>
    </marketplace>
    <creator>
        <email>admin@fakeco</email>
        <firstName>Alice</firstName>
        <lastName>Hacker</lastName>
        <openId>https://www.acme-marketplace.com/openid/id/a11a7918-bb43-4429-a256-f6d729c71033</openId>
        <uuid>a11a7918-bb43-4429-a256-f6d729c71033</uuid>
    </creator>
    <payload>
        <company>
            <uuid>d15bb36e-5fb5-11e0-8c3c-00262d2cda03</uuid>
            <email>admin@fakeco</email>
            <name>Fake Co.</name>
            <phoneNumber>1-415-555-1212</phoneNumber>
            <website>fakeco</website>
        </company>
        <order>
            <editionCode>BASIC</editionCode>
            <item>
                <quantity>10</quantity>
                <unit>USER</unit>
            </item>
        </order>
    </payload>
</event>
EOT
```

Then check the document's `errors` method, you'll see:

```
doc.errors
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError:0x100a6dbb8
        attr_reader :code = 76,
        attr_reader :column = 19,
        attr_reader :domain = 1,
        attr_reader :file = nil,
        attr_reader :int1 = 1,
        attr_reader :level = 3,
        attr_reader :line = 6,
        attr_reader :str1 = "event",
        attr_reader :str2 = "marketplace",
        attr_reader :str3 = nil
    >,
    [1] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError:0x100a6daa0
        attr_reader :code = 5,
        attr_reader :column = 5,
        attr_reader :domain = 1,
        attr_reader :file = nil,
        attr_reader :int1 = 0,
        attr_reader :level = 3,
        attr_reader :line = 7,
        attr_reader :str1 = nil,
        attr_reader :str2 = nil,
        attr_reader :str3 = nil
    >
]
```

That's Nokogiri telling you about the problems with the document. You can react to that simply enough using:

```
if (!doc.errors.empty?)
  ...
end
```

It tries to recover from errors because of the `RECOVER` flag being set in the `parse` step, but there are some cases it can't fix, such as the doubled closing tag. You'll need to do a pre-flight check and fix to cleanse the document before Nokogiri can make sense of it. Unfortunately, not all XML is generated correctly, and whoever created that should have run it through a validity checker before putting it out there. As is, it's non-conforming and considered illegal in the XML world.